# Convert type instance to dictionary

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ampl

I have an instance that I get as a result of iAMPL jupyter notebook magic. How can I convert that to a dictionary in python?

```
print(x)
```

Returns the following output:

```
{('87', '41'): 0.0, ('59', '20'): 0.0, ('32', '40'): 0.0, ('49', '2'): 0.0, ('1', '20'): 0.0, ('21', '17'): 0.0, ('92', '3'): 0.0, ('55', '30'): 0.0, ('3', '15'): 0.0, ('8', '51'): 0.0, ('24', '28'): 0.0, ('18', '44'): 0.0, ('82', '38'): 0.0, ('63', '47'): 0.0, ('102', '47'): 0.0, ('87', '11'): 0.0, ('79', '14'): 0.0, ('4', '30'): 0.0, ('63', '6'): 0.0, ('71', '10'): 0.0, ('11', '33'): 0.0, ('54', '50'): 0.0, ('25', '13'): 0.0, ('47', '24'): 0.0, ('77', '1'): 1.0, ('3', '27'): 0.0, ('73', '7'): 0.0, ('63', '17'): 0.0, ('45', '21'): 0.0, ('16', '22'): 0.0, ('23', '29'): 0.0, ('7', '1'): 0.0, ('51', '2'): 0.0, ('83', '47'): 0.0, ('65', '51'): 0.0
```

Comment: apart from the missing closing curly brace it really looks like a dictionary. Is it a string? try "`type(x)`"

Comment: Its actually much longer. The result is the output from a solver that returns a 105*56 matrix. The strings are the row and column numbers and the float is the value of the matrix. If you want I can share the code of how I got the matrix with you. I am using iAMPL, which is this http://zverovich.net/2013/01/08/ampl-magic-using-ipython-as-an-interface-to-ampl.html. On doing type(x) it returns "instance", which I have no idea how to deal with because I am seeing it for the first time

Comment: What is the result of `dict(x)`?

Comment: What is the result of type(x) ?

Comment: gives me back some random values, I am not sure what they mean. This is what it returns  http://imgur.com/a/ouLsG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm try a pragmatic approach since all attempts to find the exact type of this has failed.

Printing `x` seems to print a valid python dictionary in a string form, so what I propose (which may not be optimal) is to use x converted as `str` and feed it to `ast.literal_eval`, like this:

```
import ast

d = ast.literal_eval(str(x))
```

`d` is now a valid python dictionary:

```
print(d[('87','41')])
```

returns `0.0`

maybe there's a more elegant solution, but that does the job in the meanwhile.

Comment: Thanks, Jean. Works for now and I have a small data set so its quick enough